# how to add javascript in volusion editor

Tags: volusion

I want to add below codes in editor.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://select-box.googlecode.com/svn/tags/0.2/jquery.selectbox-0.2.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $("select").selectbox();
});
</script>
```

When will I include this file in my editor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From volition forum.

> you can add some Javascript into your template_###.htm file (via the
>   Design > File Editor page), typically on a new line immediately
>   following the  tag.

Take a look on [this](http://support.volusion.com/video/design-introduction-editing-template) video, for more detail info.